# How is the randomly generated password salt in PHP 5.5's new password_hash function even useful?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

I was just reading about the new features in PHP 5.5 and it includes new password hashing functionality (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Now if you look at the description, the default operation of it is to randomly generate a password salt if you don't specify one.

But I don't see how that is useful. Because if you are hashing the password for safe storage and the salt is random. Then when you run the string the user enters for the password through, the resulting hash will be different each time if the salt is different each time. Therefore you would be unable to compare, successfully, a valid password entered versus a stored copy of the password hash.

So how can this be useful at all?

Comment: I think the salt value is included in the hash.

Comment: `Blowfish:     $2a$07$usesomesillystringfore2uDLvp1Ii2e./U9C8sBjqp8I90dH6hi` The string has a algo signature + a salt + an hash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The salt is included in the hash value.

```
<?php

$hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => 'saltsaltsaltsaltsaltsa']);
print_r(password_get_info($hash));
echo $hash;
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [algo] => 1
    [algoName] => bcrypt
    [options] => Array
        (
            [cost] => 10
        )

)

$2y$10$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltsOPRDjePxJkNp7mjBEve63IqKPFT7ehNG
```

As you can see, the hashing function stores information about the hashing process in the hash itself. The `password_verify()` function then parses the `hash` and validates the password based on this information.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't look at the password_verify function. This makes a lot more sense now.